# Keyword '|' in Makefile Prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The MakeFile below:

```
afl-fuzz: afl-fuzz.c | test_x86
gcc afl-fuzz.c -o afl-fuzz
```

What's the meaning of '|' before `test_x86` ?

The MakeFile is from: https://github.com/loverszhaokai/AFL/blob/gcc_mode/Makefile

Comment: [Here's the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)

Comment: You might want to post an *answer* instead of updating your question with the answer. Now you have a question and an answer in one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`targets : normal-prerequisites | order-only-prerequisites`

The targets will not be updated if the `order-only-prerequisites` is changed.

Reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html